# cd into multiple directories and run commands

Tags: bash, shell, docker, hadoop-yarn, cd

Trying to automate something with a shell script..

**OS**: Mac

Want to achieve something like this:

**script.sh**

```
cd foo
yarn start
cd ..
cd bar
yarn start
cd ..
cd foobar
./start.sh
cd ..
cd boofar
docker-compose up
cd ..
echo "Go to your localhost and see your webapp working!!"
```

but these commands don't stop until I hit `^C`.

Is something like this even possible?
I tried to use `&&`, `;` etc. but can't seem to find the right combination. Also, looked into `screen` to open multiple windows but I can't seem to get that right either.

Comment: `docker-compose up` might need to be changed to `docker-compose up -d`?

Comment: first off all - `yarn run start` not `yarn start`. second - all this commands run services in the foreground, meaning the script is waiting for the task to complete before it carries on to the next command. maybe run them with `nohup`, and as @richyen stated- run `docker-compose` in detached mode: `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Thanks @richyen and @Efrat. In my case, the `yarn run start` commands don't need to be sequential.

Answer (score 1):

I think you intend to put each of the sub-commands into the background. To do this, you add an ampersand to the end of each command. If these child-processes are writing to stdout/stderr, you should prefix them with 'nohup' and redirect output to some form of log file:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd foo
nohup yarn start > {/log/file1} &
cd ..
cd bar
nohup yarn start > {/log/file2} &
cd ..
cd foobar
nohup ./start.sh > {/log/file3} &
cd ..
cd boofar
nohup docker-compose up > {/log/file4} &
cd ..
echo "Go to your localhost and see your webapp working!!"
```

You can also put the common functionality in a function to make the whole script more readable:

```
#!/bin/bash

function start_child() {
  cd "${1}"
  logfile="${2}"
  shift 2
  nohup "${@}" > ${logfile} &
  cd ..
}

start_child foo /log/file1 yarn start
start_child bar /log/file2 yarn start
start_child foobar /log/file3 ./start.sh
start_child boofar /log/file3 docker-compose up
echo "Go to your localhost and see your webapp working!!"
```

Note: If any of the child processes try to read input from the terminal, then they will hang.